# ASP.NET WebAPI how to make a POST request creating user with all data

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm playing around with ASP.NET WebAPI and so far I have some of the CRUD operations working. However my Create operation is not fully working.

With the following POST request (JSON) I am able to create an User.

```
{Username:"Bob", FirstName:"Foo", LastName:"Bar", Password:"123", Headline:"Tuna"}
```

However the object `User` actually has more attributes - collection of addresses.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public int Cycle { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
... ...
```

I'm not sure how to create the User with one or more Addresses as I don't know what the next Address ID has to be and what the corresponding UserId it needs to have.

**UPDATE2**:

See my answer for solution.

twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the Id column Identity so the database takes care of incrementing. Thereby I can post the following JSON http post request.

```
{ "Addresses": [ { "StreetName": "Bigfoot Street", "Country": "AB", "ZipCode": "1234", "Cycle": 1, }, { "StreetName": "Woo Way Avenue", "Country": "AC", "ZipCode": "7777", "Cycle": 2, } ], "Phonenumbers": [ { "Number": "99999999", "Cycle": 3, } ], "Emails": [ { "Uemail": "bigfoot@example.com", "Cycle": 4, } ], "Positions": [], "Username": "Bigfoot", "FirstName": "Foo", "LastName": "Bar", "Password": "123", "Headline": "Pro" }
```

And Entity Framework takes care of assigning id's to everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
[ { ... }, { ... } ]
```

You just created an array of two objects.
It doesn't make sense to convert that into a single `Address` instance.

Instead, you need to create a single object with multiple properties:

```
{ StreetName:"Madison Square Garden", Country:"OP" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way. You create the entire object graph, which is the `User` object with all the properties set and just return it through a `Get` action method and let web API serialize your graph into JSON. You can use that JSON from Fiddler or whatever to POST.

```
public User Get(int id)
{
   return new User()
   {
      UserId = id, UserName = "Arnold", ...,
      Addresses = new List<Address>()
      {
         new Address() { ... }
      },
      PhoneNumbers = ...
   };
}
```

Comment: Check my first post please I pasted the JSON and my question along. Cheers

Comment: I'm not very sure if I understand your problem fully but I guess the answer to your question depends on how you have mapped the EF entities, if the underlying tables use identity column, how you are persisting the graph and all that. If you do not want user ID to be bound, you can leave them out of JSON. BTW, it is not a good practice to bind request directly to your entity classes.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not a good practice to bind request directly to your entity classes". How else would it work? :/

Comment: You can use a DTO and map it to your entity class using a library like AutoMapper, for example.

Comment: Would you be able to guide me towards some articles or hint me in a direction where I could read more about this specific matter. To why it's not a good practice etc. Now that you mentioned I want to know more. Cheers!

Comment: Check this out, specifically over-posting: `http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api`